# How can I create a Minecraft: Bedrock Edition add-on?

Tags: minecraft-modding

I would like to create a custom add-on for Minecraft: Bedrock Edition, but I'm not understanding everything involved with getting started. After reading a few tutorials, I have *some* understanding of what to do, but there is nothing that wholly gives an up-to-date complete process of how to do so.

How can I create a custom add-on for Minecraft: Bedrock Edition?

---

Note that I've decided to post this question/answer because of the issues described above. I thought it would help others avoid doing all the research I had to go through.

###### Related Posts

| Title |
| --- |
| [How To: Create Custom Blocks](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/376769/how-do-i-make-a-custom-block-with-minecraft-addons/376770#376770) |
| [How To: Rename Items](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/381159/how-do-i-rename-an-item-with-add-ons/381160#381160) |

Comment: Fwiw, I don't think this should be closed. To be "dishonest", the question could be reworded in such a way that it reads as the OP tried outdated tutorial X and is getting stuck because reason Y. Then the answer would be "the tutorial is outdated, here is the complete way you need to go with the current version." There are situations where an OP tried hard to solve an issue and is happy to share their findings, and I think it is the case here.

Comment: @Vaillancourt does that read a bit better?

Comment: I think the fact that you ask and answer at the same time removes a bit of the "enforcement" we have to do on questions. Asking for lists of tools, lists of resources, list of links,  list of X is off-topic, but the question, in this case, does not require that you request any of those: you're free to provide those in the answer, along with a good set of instructions. I believe that your question does not contain anything off-topic at the moment, and that it is correctly scoped and on-topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Objectives

After reading this answer through and through, you should be able to effectively answer the following questions:

- What is an add-on?

  - What is a resource pack?
  - What is a behavior pack?
  - What is the difference between the two?
- What does `JSON` stand for?

  - What is `JSON` used for?
- What tools are required to create an add-on?
- What official resources are available for creating add-ons?
- What official documentation is available for reference when creating add-ons?

#### Overview

Creating add-ons for Minecraft: Bedrock Edition (henceforth referred to as simply BE) is a relatively straightforward process that, more often than not, requires little to no knowledge of programming. Getting started, you'll need to have an understanding of some basic terminology:

| Term | General Definition |
| --- | --- |
| Resource Pack | *A partial add-on for Minecraft that enables creators to alter the **appearance** of the Minecraft worlds that implement them.* |
| Behavior pack | *A partial add-on for Minecraft (specifc to BE) that enables creators to alter the **behavior** of the items and entities used in the Minecraft worlds that implement them.* |
| JSON | ***JavaScript Object Notation** is a lightweight format for storing and transporting data that is often used when data is sent from a server to a web page. It is "self-describing" and easy to understand.* |
| UUID | *A universally unique identifier (**UUID**) is a 128-bit label used for information in computer systems. The term globally unique identifier (**GUID**) is also used, often in software created by Microsoft. When generated according to the standard methods, UUIDs are, for practical purposes, unique.* |
| .mcpack | *The file extension used for individual resource or behavior **packs**. This is used in a one or the other situation.* |
| .mcaddon | *The file extension used for **add-ons**. This is used when there is a resource ***and*** behavior pack included in a single package.* |

#### Required Tools

The only tools ***required*** for creating an add-on for BE are text editors. Some of the most popular OS agnostic text editors are:

- [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/)
- [Atom](https://atom.io/)
- [Sublime Text](https://www.sublimetext.com/)

Alternatively, [here is an article](https://www.techradar.com/best/best-text-editors) reviewing a list of 10 text editors that are OS agnostic.

#### Getting Started

Once you've chosen and installed the text editor of your choice, the first thing you'll want to do is download [the vanilla packs](https://www.minecraft.net/en-us/addons). The vanilla packs are going to be a point of reference for anything and everything (excluding scripts) that you may want to accomplish with your custom add-on. It is also recommended that you watch [the official introduction to add-ons](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=US67Tlb8gyE) video.

Once you've downloaded the vanilla packs, feel free to explore their contents and get familiar with the structure:

[image: Screenshot of the folder structure and an open manifest file in Visual Studio Code.]

<sub>***Note**: I'm using Visual Studio Code in the screenshot above, but you can browse the folder structure in the file explorer or text editor of your choosing.*</sub>

#### Hello Minecraft

Now that you've familiarized yourself with the content structure of the vanilla packs, you're ready to start getting your feet wet by creating your very first add-on. The basic requirements of an add-on are:

- A resource ***or*** behavior pack.

  - A manifest file describing that pack.

You're probably wondering, "is that it?!", well, yeah, it is. Your add-on doesn't actually require a behavior pack ***and*** a resource pack. In-fact, only one ***or*** the other is required, though both can be included. For the purposes of this answer, the resulting add-on will include both.

To get started, create a folder with the name of your add-on (I called mine ***Hello Minecraft***) and then two folders within that one called ***Behavior Pack*** and ***Resource Pack*** respectively (henceforth referred to jointly as the pack folders). Within the newly created pack folders, create a file named `manifest` with a file extension of `.json`. The resulting stucture should look like this:

[image: Screenshot of the basic file structure in Visual Studio Code.]

The manifest file is different for behavior packs and resource packs. However, you can grab a sample of both from the vanilla packs to populate the files you just created. Next, you'll need to generate ***four*** UUIDs two for each pack. Both packs have a header UUID and a module UUID:

```
{
    "format_version": 2,
    "header": {
        "description": "An example resource pack for demonstration purposes.",
        "name": "Hello Minecraft! - Resources (0.0.1)",
        "uuid": "efcd2de9-44b2-4201-ba94-6b82ef59de0f",
        "version": [0, 0, 1],
        "min_engine_version": [ 1, 17, 0 ]
    },
    "modules": [
        {
            "description": "An example resource pack for demonstration purposes.",
            "type": "resources",
            "uuid": "fca45bed-c308-42ad-9b54-690083e7dc3e",
            "version": [0, 0, 1]
        }
    ]
}
```

The manifest file has an additional field available labeled `dependencies` which you'll see in the vanilla behavior pack manifest:

```
"dependencies": [
    {
        "uuid": "efcd2de9-44b2-4201-ba94-6b82ef59de0f",
        "version": [0, 0, 1]
    }
]
```

The UUID in this section is set to the header UUID of the respective dependency. So in the case of this add-on, the behavior pack will be dependent on the resource pack. As a result, the dependency UUID is the header UUID of the resource pack.

#### Bundling and Importing

Once you've set your UUIDs, you can then bundle your add-on and import it into Minecraft! To do this, you can store the folders relevant to your add-on (in this case the pack folders) in a single archive file (commonly referred to as `.zip` files, but this can vary based on OS). After you've placed your add-on contents into an archive file, you can change the file's extension to `.mcaddon` which will allow you to open the add-on with Minecraft. Importing is as simple as opening the file with Minecraft, from there the process is automated.

Once imported, you should see your packs in Minecraft:

[image: Screenshot of the resource pack after a successful import into Minecraft for Windows 10.]

#### Further Reading

Now that you've created your first custom add-on for Minecraft: Bedrock Edition, you may be curious as to what documentation is available to you. Fortunately, the vanilla packs include some basic, but official documentation within the behavior pack:

[image: Screenshot of the documentation files within the behavior pack.]

In addition to this, there are online resources (such as [Bedrock.dev](https://bedrock.dev/docs/1.17.0.0/1.17.20.23/Addons)) that add styling to the aforementioned documentation, making it easier to follow, along with [official resources from Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/minecraft/creator/documents/gettingstarted). Also, [the fandom wiki](https://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/Minecraft_Wiki) is a great resource to utilize when trying to [find data values](https://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/Bedrock_Edition_data_values) and really detailed information about Minecraft in general.

---

<sub>***Note**: The add-on created for this answer is available [on GitHub](https://github.com/tacoexchange/minecraft-hello-world) for those interested in reviewing the complete package.*</sub>

Comment: A good thorough answer, plus it's a nice bonus to be able to see the add-on on GitHub :) +1

Comment: @Joachim thank you!